# Rename final part of a directory following final forwardslash

Tags: linux

I have a list of directories in a text file, which I am looping through.  I simply want to rename the final part of the directory to a standardized name (this is the part of the directory after the final forwardslash).  Is there a simple way to identify the final part of a file name and rename it in a loop?

For example, the directories are ...

```
/data/images/projects/MM/1/scans/16/7__ep2d_fid_basic_bold_293_Resting_State
/data/images/projects/MM/1/scans/20/7__ep2d_fid_basic_bold_293_Resting_State
/data/images/projects/MM/1/scans/03/8
```

I want to change them to...

```
/data/images/projects/MM/1/scans/16/rs
/data/images/projects/MM/1/scans/20/rs
/data/images/projects/MM/1/scans/03/rs
```

I can't figure out a way to do this, although it should be simple.  Sorry, a newbie here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a small script that will do the job for you.

It will read the content of an input file, remove everything after last slash + slash sign, and append /rs at the end, and then write the changes to a new file (called output.txt).

Create a script.sh and chmod +x it and add the following to it,

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./script.sh input.txt, where input.txt is your input file with the
# raw data you want to change.

while IFS='' read -r line
do
    name=$line
    echo "Before: $name"
    name=`echo $name | awk -F '/'  '{ for(i=1; i<=8; i++) {print $i} }' | tr '\n' '/'|sed 's/.$//'`
    echo "$name/rs" >> output.txt
done < "$1"

# EOF
```

Run it by typing `./script.sh input.txt` in the console.

Note: This is one way of doing it and it probably fits your current specific problem. It does not update the input file. Rather, it creates a new file (output.txt) with the new content.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This seems to have worked.  I had no idea it would be so complicated though!  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while IFS='' read -r line
    do
        name=$line
        echo "Before: $name"
        name=`echo $name | awk -F '/'  '{ for(i=1; i<=10; i++) {print $i} }' | tr '\n' '/'|sed 's/.$//'`
        echo "$name/rsfMRI" > /sdata/images/projects/ASD_MM/1/datafiles/output.txt
        for y in $(cat /sdata/images/projects/ASD_MM/1/datafiles/output.txt); do
        mv $line $y
        done
    done < "$1"
```

Comment: I made a few changes to the script above to directly change the file name as the above script was just inserting into a text file (not sure if I did something wrong).  Thanks so much for your help mattias.